# How to show the contents of a sqlite table in a QTableView and update the DB and have the results show in QTableView?

Tags: python, sqlite, qt5, qtableview

I want to update a table/insert new item with an execute statement in qt and I want the table to immediately show this new data. What is the simplest possible example to do this?

I am using python, sqllite and pyqt5. I have been looking for how to do this but without success.

I am assuming it won't hog the UI or maybe you have to use threading then. In that case, I want to use QThread.

edit: ok i found an example which i converted to PyQt5, added an edit func and cleaned up. Now just need to figure out how to delete all entries at once and see if using a model with qthread and sqlite will be responsive:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtSql

def initializeModel(model):
    model.setTable('sportsmen')
    model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    model.select()
    model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
    model.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "First name")
    model.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Last name")

def createView(title, model):
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setWindowTitle(title)
    return view

def addrow():
    print(model.rowCount())
    ret = model.insertRows(model.rowCount(), 1)
    print(ret)

def editrow():
    model.setData(model.index(1, 1), "LEL")
    #model.submitAll()

def findrow(i):
    delrow = i.row()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('sports.db')
    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    delrow = -1
    initializeModel(model)

    view1 = createView("Table Model (View 1)", model)
    view1.clicked.connect(findrow)

    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(view1)

    addBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add a row")
    addBtn.clicked.connect(addrow)
    layout.addWidget(addBtn)

    editBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("edit a row")
    editBtn.clicked.connect(editrow)
    layout.addWidget(editBtn)

    delBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("del a row")
    delBtn.clicked.connect(lambda: 
    model.removeRow(view1.currentIndex().row()))
    layout.addWidget(delBtn)
    dialog.setLayout(layout)
    dialog.setWindowTitle("Database Demo")
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Qt o PyQt4 o PyQt5?

Comment: like i said, PyQt5.

Comment: It shows what you have tried, even if it does not work, there are many examples in the internet. I find it strange that you do not find any.

Comment: I updated answer now. Found 1 example for PyQt4 which i converted to PyQt5.

Comment: Why do you want to use QThread?

Comment: Because i will be adding/removing/editing a lot of entries and want my GUI to be responsive when it happens...